# .width(variable) as a percentage instead of pixels

Tags: jquery

I have a variable `perc` which is a number that changes from 0 to 100. When I use jquery to adjust the width of a progress bar it just does it in pixels.

```
var perc = ((first/constant)*100).toFixed(0);

.width(perc)
```

How can I do it as a percentage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the `%` symbol after the number

```
.width(perc+'%')
```

If you read the [documentation of the `.width(value)` method](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width-value) you will see that it accepts both numbers and strings..

> If a ***string*** is provided, however, any valid CSS measurement may be used for the width (*such as **`100px`**, **`50%`**, or **`auto`***).

Comment: Cheers. I was trying `.width(perc,'%')` for some weird reason!

Comment: but its not working for me. i tried with .width(perc,'%'), .width(perc+'%') and also .css('width', perc + '%').

Comment: @Preethi first of all there should be a jQuery object before the `.` like `$('selector-here').width(..)`. Then the item you try to resize should be a block element so that it can have specific width and not be defined by its contents alone.. so if you could create an example where it fails i can have a look

Comment: $("#panel1").css('width',31+'%'); $("#panel2").width(68+'%'); both of this solution didn't work for me and also i tried with .width(perc,'%').. didn't work.

Comment: @Preethi and what type of elements are `#panel1` and `#panel2` ?(*can you recreate an example at http://jsfiddle.net and post the link here ?*)

Answer (score 1):

Use .css() instead

```
.css('width', perc + '%')
```