# Changing width of div in % syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Very simple question, just having trouble with syntax.

I have a `var` skill which is some number.

I need to change the width of a div based on `skill` when a button is clicked in terms of % but I'm not sure what the syntax is:

```
$('.div').css("width",100-skill) // How to do 100-skill in %?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207899/widthvariable-as-a-percentage-instead-of-pixels

Comment: If you have your reply, don't forgot to check your question ;)

Comment: Is expected result that number `skill` would be a percentage of existing `width` as a percentage ? Can include `html`, `css` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: It's a skill bar. It has two divs. The first is (say 500px in width), then this div I'm using is on top which changes based on skill. If skill = 0, then it's 100% which means it covers the entire underneath div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like that ?

```
var percent = 100 - skill;
$('.div').css("width", percent + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a % sign at the end.

```
$('.div').css("width", 100-skill + '%');
```

JavaScript is capable of recognizing this as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use string

```
(100 - skill) + '%'
```